# Jenkins does not interpret windows batch commands properly

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

Hey guys I do have the following batch file/commands:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
IF EXIST C:\myapp (
set /p pid =< C:\myapp\RUNNING_PID
echo !pid!
taskkill /PID !pid! /F
DEL RUNNING_PID
rmdir C:\myapp /s /q
)
endlocal
mkdir C:\myapp
xcopy /E "C:\Program Files  (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\myapp\target\universal\myappDist\myapp-1.0"  C:\myapp
start java.exe -Dpidfile.path=C:\myapp\RUNNING_PID -Dhttp.port=3000 -cp C:\myapp\lib\* play.core.server.NettyServer
```

However, Jenkins does not interpret it properly. It always tries to execute the following:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
IF EXIST C:\myapp (
set /p pid = 0<C:\myapp\RUNNING_PID  
echo !pid!  
taskkill /PID !pid! /F  
DEL RUNNING_PID  
rmdir C:\lexia /s /q 
)
```

The remaining lines of code are interpreted again properly. I don't have any clue what's going on here.

Hope someone can give me a hint.

Thanks already in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by replacing this:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
IF EXIST C:\myapp (
set /p pid =< C:\myapp\RUNNING_PID
echo !pid!
taskkill /PID !pid! /F
DEL RUNNING_PID
rmdir C:\myapp /s /q
)
endlocal
```

with:

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
IF EXIST C:\myapp\ (
    set/p pid=<C:\myapp\RUNNING_PID
    echo %pid%
    taskkill /PID %pid% /F
    DEL RUNNING_PID
    rmdir C:\myapp /s /q
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! In fact it did work, and the problem was a complete different one why it did not work. However, the echo of the script was the one above, because of what you just suggested! Because even after I fixed my problem and the script was working, the echo was still not proplery!